# TableView Cell Not Showing Content and Not Responding To Commands

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xcode-storyboard

When working in the storyboard I can add labels and imageviews to a tableview cell but when I run the app they will not show. The only way I can get them to show is if they are in a stackview on a view within the cell. The cell will only not change colors on run time even if the cell's background color is changed in the storyboard. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: You need to show at least some code for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

You should give us more insight to your project - that means your code, possibly your storyboard...
It's hard to tell what you did wrong when we even don't know what you **did**.

- Did you connect your objects with outlets?
- If you defined your own cells, did you selected them in storyboard?
- How about your TableView Delegates?